# tdcs4-ms-reg.exe using 90% CPU

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

In one of our production servers (Windows Server 2008), we were having some performance issues when a process `tdcs4-ms-reg.exe` was using up more than 90% of CPU. When this process was killed, everything went normal.

This process is located in the system folder `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\`

Does anyone have idea what this process is ?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably its a spyware/Virus.
First run a through spyware/antivirus test to verify if the system is clean, then run a utility "processXP", which will show you detailed properties of process, that what is it doing, how many threads it has opened, how many network connections it has opened etc etc.